# Author website URL

Tags: author

I've assigned a specific html page (let's call it an author bio page) to each user in the 'website' field within the user admin area.  How do I get that URL to display within a single page post?  I'm assuming that I'm to use $curauth->user_url but it returns a blank page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to assign `$curauth` and since you are not on an author archive but on a regular page you can use [get_userdata](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) function and pass the user ID like so:

```
$curauth = get_userdata(1);
//and then use 
echo $curauth->user_url;
```

or if you are in the loop you can use `the_author_link();` which will Displays the author's Website URL as a link and the text for the link is the author's Profile Display name publicly as field.

Comment: Thank you, Bainternet!  You have helped me tremendously on this and other issues and I really appreciate you explaining the reason behind your solution so that I'm better able to help myself by understanding the reasons why.  I love this forum!

Comment: Glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

use [`the_author_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_link):

```
<?php the_author_link(); ?>
```